# findbugs-maven-plugin throws OutOfMemoryError

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin, out-of-memory, findbugs

findbugs-maven-plugin throws OutOfMemoryError, how to fix this

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:14
2)
        at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:
67)
        at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassPars
er.java:225)
        at org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:136
)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.bcel.JavaClassAnalysisEngin
e.analyze(JavaClassAnalysisEngine.java:55)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.bcel.JavaClassAnalysisEngin
e.analyze(JavaClassAnalysisEngine.java:43)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysi
s(AnalysisCache.java:213)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.bcel.ClassContextClassAnaly
sisEngine.analyze(ClassContextClassAnalysisEngine.java:46)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.bcel.ClassContextClassAnaly
sisEngine.analyze(ClassContextClassAnalysisEngine.java:38)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysi
s(AnalysisCache.java:213)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.isTooBig(AnalysisContext.
java:385)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.analyzeApplication(FindBugs2.java:
949)
        at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:222)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessor
Impl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethod
AccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.
java:86)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:756)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(Invok
erHelper.java:778)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHe
lper.java:758)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(
ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:170)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethod0(
ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:198)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindBugsMojo.executeReport(FindBugsMo
jo.groovy:792)
        at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(Abstract
MavenReport.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractM
avenReport.java:66)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
PluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals
(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStand
aloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(
DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Windows machine, the following command will increase the maximum amount of memory made available to Maven (heap and permGen respectively):

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass a heap size to FindBugs with -maxHeap